# Find a file in current or parent directories

Tags: file-system, rust

As a Rust beginner, I would like to know how I could improve the following points considering the function below:

- Handling `Path` and `PathBuf` types correctly;
- Performance;
- Rust writing style in general.

Here is the function, decorated with a full working example:

```
use std::env;
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};

const RUSV_FILENAME: &str = ".rusv.json";

/**
 * Find a rusv file in the current or parent directories of the given directory.
 */
fn find_rusv_file(starting_directory: &Path) -> Option<PathBuf> {
    let mut directory = starting_directory;
    let rusv_filename = Path::new(&RUSV_FILENAME);

    loop {
        let filepath: PathBuf = [
            directory,
            rusv_filename
        ].iter().collect();

        if filepath.is_file() {
            return Some(filepath);
        }

        match directory.parent() {
            Some(parent) => directory = parent,
            None => return None,
        }
    }
}

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let path = env::current_dir()?;

    match find_rusv_file(&path) {
        Some(filepath) => println!("Rusv file was found: {:?}", filepath),
        None => println!("No rusv file was found."),
    };

    Ok(())
}
```

My question is *not* about:

- Creating a more generic function (e.g. by giving the filename as an argument);
- Anything related to the `main()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Handling Path and PathBuf types correctly;

My concern is that you recreate `PathBuf` every time, I don't see the point to have a buffer if you don't use it.

> Performance;

I think it's ok, you search one file in particular the time you take creating the string is cheap compare to system call. So I don't think `read_dir` is better on your case. This could be benchmarked.

> Rust writing style in general.

You are using `return`, on your case maybe use `break` to make your function SESE (single entry single exit).

`Path::new(&RUSV_FILENAME);` the reference is not needed `Path::new(RUSV_FILENAME);`.

```rust
fn find_rusv_file(starting_directory: &Path) -> Option<PathBuf> {
    let mut path: PathBuf = starting_directory.into();
    let file = Path::new(RUSV_FILENAME);

    loop {
        path.push(file);

        if path.is_file() {
            break Some(path);
        }

        if !(path.pop() && path.pop()) { // remove file && remove parent
            break None;
        }
    }
}
```